# Setting up a triple integral in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm confused on how to get my $\theta$ limits for my triple integral. The question reads as follows:

Let D be the region inside a cylinder whose base in the $xy$-plane is the circle $r=3\cos\theta$ and whose top is in the plane $z = 5 - x$. Set up an interated integral for calculating $\iint_D \left( x^2 + y^2 \right) \, dV$.

Is there a way I am able to find my $\theta$ from $r=3\cos\theta$? I'm confused my teacher gave us the limits as $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and I have no idea how they came to that conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The circle $r=3\cos \theta$ can be transformed to Cartesian coordinates as $r^2=3r\cos \theta; x^2+y^2=3x; (x^2-\frac 32)+y^2=\frac 94$, so it has center $(\frac 32,0)$ and radius $\frac 32$.  It passes through the origin with a vertical tangent, so is entirely in the first and fourth quadrants.  This represents the range in $\theta$ of $[-\frac \pi2,\frac \pi 2]$

Comment: Alright i think the idea now, if you can help me with another question im given r = 2$/sin/theta/$, he listed that the theta as 0 to pi/4. Wouldn't its range be be 0 to pi?

Comment: Yes, it would seem so.  Maybe there is some symmetry that lets you reduce the range.

Answer (score 1):

Drawing a nice plot of $r=3\cos(\theta)$ makes the points clear telling us why we have: $$\theta|_{-\pi/2}^{+\pi/2}$$ Note that because of $z$, the symmetric of flat region below on $xy$ plane may be useless.

[image]

Comment: Nice plot! +1 ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks my dear friend. I hope you get well.